# What is it $\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(B\cap C)}$?

Tags: conditional-probability, joint-distribution

(My question is prompted by [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258379/why-is-pa-bc-pbc-pab-c/329777#329777) post.)

I'm not understanding why $\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(B\cap C)}$is not equal to $\frac{P(A)P(B)P(C)}{P(B)P(C)} = P(A)$. I know it's wrong but I cannot understand why. Can you explain it please?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted so hard. Seems to be a reasonable, albeit elementary, question regarding dependence/independence.

Comment: The first step you give is only true if A, B and C are mutually independent; otherwise it is not true.

Comment: Are we sure about the tags here? There's nothing inherently Bayesian about intersecting probabilities.

Answer (score 4):

If $A$, $B$, and $C$ are mutually independent you can say $P(A\cap B\cap C)= P(A)P(B)P(C)$. But, in general case, they are not independent, and you can't always say that.

Comment: can you be specific about the "vice versa" that doesn't hold?

Comment: @AdamO I mean if $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$, we can't conclude that $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Comment: @OmG what you said is incorrect; that is the definition of independence of two events $A$ and $B$. If that equation is satisfied, $A$ and $B$ are independent. However, in order for three events $A,B,C$ to be independent, four criteria must be satisfied: 

$$P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B), \quad P(A\cap C) = P(A)P(C), \\ P(B\cap C) = P(B)P(C), \quad P(A\cap B \cap C) = P(A)P(B)P(C).$$

Comment: @MartinL I've updated my answer.

Comment: It's still not correct. Here is an example when $A, B, C$ are not independent, but $P\left(A \cap B \cap C \right) = P\left(A\right) P\left(B\right) P\left(C\right)$: (link in next comment):

Comment: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BodHDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT42&lpg=PT42&dq=an%20example%20when%20the%20probability%20of%20the%20intersection%20of%20three%20events%20equals%20the%20product%20of%20the%20probabilities%20without%20independence&source=bl&ots=k-UXBAwpQ_&sig=aTJW86SsNGAqpjid7HuF8znrfg8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU9ebvuLnZAhUHJcAKHZEhB1QQ6AEIcDAF#v=onepage&q=an%20example%20when%20the%20probability%20of%20the%20intersection%20of%20three%20events%20equals%20the%20product%20of%20the%20probabilities%20without%20independence&f=false

Comment: @oszkar ok. it might be. But it is not true in genreal case as I've mentioned. In the other words, you can say $P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A)P(B)P(C)$, if you don't have any pre-knowldge about dependency of $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Comment: Counterexamples in Probability And Statistics By A.F. Siegel: 1.11 Three events such that the probability of the intersection is equal to the product of the probabilities even though the events are not independent

The book title and the counterexample data for the link above. It's a great book by the way.

Comment: @OmG OK, you're right, not correct is not a good word. But it can be misleading, as in the case when they are not independent it might or might not be true. Maybe it's better to write something like "you can't always say that". But that's just my opinion.

Comment: If we're going to be pedantic about this, you should probably say that $A$, $B$, and $C$ are mutually independent.

Comment: @Clarinetist good point. it's updated.

Answer (score 0):

It could be wrong, and it could be right, based on the independency/dependency of the events. Of course it's not generally true.

An example when it's not true:

Lets say
\begin{align*}
  \Omega &:= \left\{ x \in \mathbb{Z} \; : \; 1 \le x \le 31 \right\}, \\
  A &:= \left\{ x \in \Omega \; : \; 2|x \right\}, \\
  B &:= \left\{ x \in \Omega \; : \; 3|x \right\}, \\
  C &:= \left\{ x \in \Omega \; : \; 5|x \right\}
\end{align*}

In this case:
\begin{align*}
  A \cap B \cap C &:= \left\{ x \in \Omega \; : \; 30|x \right\}, \\
  B \cap C &:= \left\{ x \in \Omega \; : \; 15|x \right\}
\end{align*}

And the corresponding probabilities:
\begin{align*}
  P\left(A\right) &= \frac{15}{31} \\
  P\left(B\right) &= \frac{10}{31} \\
  P\left(C\right) &= \frac{6}{31} \\
  P\left(A \cap B \cap C\right) &= \frac{1}{31} \\
  P\left(B \cap C\right) &= \frac{2}{31}
\end{align*}

Hence:
\begin{align*}
  \frac{P\left(A \cap B \cap C\right)}{P\left(B \cap C\right)} &= \frac{\frac{1}{31}}{\frac{2}{31}} = \frac{1}{2}\\
  \frac{P\left(A\right) P\left(B\right) P\left(C\right)}{P\left(B\right) P\left(C\right)} &= P\left(A\right) = \frac{15}{31}
\end{align*}

And they are not equal. (And also $P\left(A \cap B \cap C\right) \ne P\left(A\right) P\left(B\right) P\left(C\right)$, so $A, B, C$ are not independent.)

(Some homework (as an example when it's true, remark what a small difference is enough): check for $\Omega := \left\{ x \in \mathbb{Z} \; : \; 1 \le x \le 30 \right\}$. It will be true, and $A, B, C$ will be independent. So it can be true, but not always, just in the case of independence.)

Comment: I always wandered what's wrong with this answer (as it was downvoted). Can anyone help?

Comment: -1 you spelled wandered as wondered

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the three different domains A, B, C as shown below. A∩B∩C is the red colored surface. What you ask is similar to the Bayes' rule:

Given that A and B occur, what is the probability that C also occurs?

[image]

This is basically the probability $P(C|A,B)$ or if you prefer $P(C|A∩B)$, and this is given by Bayes' rule:

$$P(C|A,B) = \frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(A,B)}$$

If I use the colors from the picture above $\frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(A,B)} = \frac{\text{red}}{\text{red+brown}}$.

Comment: Isn't $\frac{P\left(A, B, C\right)}{P\left(A, B\right)} = \frac{\text{red}}{\text{red} + \text{brown}}$?

Comment: Yes you are right. I will change it!

Comment: So that's OK and correct. But $\frac{P\left(A\right) P\left(B\right) P\left(C\right)}{P\left(B\right) P\left(C\right)} = P\left(A\right) = \text{green} + \text{light brown} + \text{red} + \text{brown}$. Can you say if it's equal to $\frac{\text{red}}{\text{red} + \text{brown}}$ or not?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but at this point my question is: isn't it red=P(A)P(B)P(C)? I got it is like this if they are mutually exclusive, but if not how can i make it?

Comment: @LorenzoB. Indeed $P(A,B,C) = \text{red}$ but you can't say that $P(A)P(B)P(C) = \text{red}$.

Comment: @oszkar What you have written doesn't hold for the graph above. $\frac{\text{red}}{\text{red}+\text{brown}} \neq \text{green} + \text{light brown} + \text{red} + \text{brown}$.

Comment: @elkoul: for those sets (or domains) (without any further information about the cardinalities of the sets and their intersects) how can you tell if it's equal or not? I understand what you want to say, but the graph ALONE does not testify that, its just an illustration (although a useful one).

Comment: And anyway, the question is about $P\left(B \cap C\right)$, which means $\frac{red}{red + blue}$, what could or could not equal $red + light brown + red + brown$ according to the independence/dependence of the events (check the two examples I have given).